# Writing an aggregation query in MongodB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my sample document structure e.g.

```
{
    "my_object": {
        "1": {
            "seq": "1",
            "time": "xyz",
        },
        "2": {
            "seq": "2",
            "time": "abc",
            "sub_aray": {
                "0": {
                    "value": 10
                },
                "1": {
                    "value": 10
                },
                "2": {
                    "value": -10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what I want to achieve is, Sum of all the sub_array's value if exists, if sub_array isn't found, default it to 0

```
{"seq" : "1", "sub_array" : 0},
{"seq" : "2", "sub_array" : 10}
```

My Mongo version is 3.4.6 and I am using PyMongo as my driver.

Comment: can you please provide proper json format.

Comment: @turivishal Apologies, it should be fixed now.

Comment: Why seq2 is 20 instead 10?

Comment: Thanks for catching it, it was a typo Gibbs.

Comment: I was trying to use map and then just sum the "values" attribute, but the issue is coming when the input to the map's "input" is not present itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xvYTMXsYapo)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "array": { //To remove dynamic keys - 1,2,etc
        "$objectToArray": "$my_object"
      }
    }
  },
  {//reshaping array
    "$unwind": "$array"
  },
  {
    $project: {//reshaping sub array to access via a static name
      "k": {
        "$objectToArray": "$array.v.sub_aray"
      },
      "seq": "$array.v.seq"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {//actual logic, output structure
      "sub_array": {
        $sum: "$k.v.value"
      },
      "_id": 0,
      "seq": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Wow! This is super clean ❤️! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Gibbs, Would appreciate if you can also share your thoughts on this question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/q/65857866/6524169 ; Thanks a lot for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

The trick part is to use the `$objectToArray` operator to iterate `my_object` items.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "my_object": {
        "$map": {
          input: {
            "$objectToArray": "$my_object"
          },
          as: "obj",
          in: {
            seq: "$$obj.v.seq",
            sub_array: {
              $sum: {
                $map: {
                  input: {
                    "$objectToArray": "$$obj.v.sub_aray"
                  },
                  as: "sub",
                  in: "$$sub.v.value"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$my_object"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$my_object"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2KGNrdfxrU0)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the map approach as well!❤️