# How to retrieve each single array element from mongo pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, aggregation

Let's assume that this is how a sample document looks like in mongo-db,

```py
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "attrib_1": "value_1",
    "attrib_2": "value_2",
    "months": {
      "2": {
        "month": "2",
        "year": "2008",
        "transactions": [
          {
            "field_1": "val_1",
            "field_2": "val_2",
            
          },
          {
            "field_1": "val_4",
            "field_2": "val_5",
            "field_3": "val_6"
          },
          
        ]
      },
      "3": {
        "month": "3",
        "year": "2018",
        "transactions": [
          {
            "field_1": "val_7",
            "field_3": "val_9"
          },
          {
            "field_1": "val_10",
            "field_2": "val_11",
            
          },
          
        ]
      },
      
    }
  }
]
```

The desired output is something like this, (I am just showing it for months 2 & 3)

| id | months | year | field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2008 | val_1 | val_2 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 2008 | val_4 | val_5 | val_6 |
| 1 | 3 | 2018 | val_7 |  | val_9 |
| 1 | 3 | 2018 | val_10 | val_11 |  |

My attempt:

I tried something like this in Py-Mongo,

```py
pipeline = [
    {
        # some filter logic here to filter data basically first
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "latest": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": {
                        "$objectToArray": "$months",
                    },
                    "as": "obj",
                    "in": {
                        "all_field_1" : {"$ifNull" : ["$$obj.v.transactions.field_1", [""]]},
                        "all_field_2": {"$ifNull" : ["$$obj.v.transactions.field_2", [""]]},
                        "all_field_3": {"$ifNull" : ["$$obj.v.transactions.field_3", [""]]},
                        "all_months" : {"$ifNull" : ["$$obj.v.month", ""]},
                        "all_years" : {"$ifNull" : ["$$obj.v.year", ""]},
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "months": "$latest.all_months",
            "year":  "$latest.all_years",
            "field_1": "$latest.all_field_1",
            "field_2": "$latest.all_field_2",
            "field_3": "$latest.all_field_3",

        }
    }
]

# and I executed it as
my_db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

The above is actually bring the data but it's bringing them in lists. Is there a way to easily bring them one each row in mongo itself?

the above brings data in this way,

| id | months | year | field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ["2", "3"] | ["2008", "2018"] | [["val_1", "val_4"], ["val_7", "val_10"]] | [["val_2", "val_5"], ["", "val_11"]] | [["", "val_6"], ["val_9", ""]] |

Would highly appreciate your valuable inputs regarding the same and a better way to do the same as well!

Thanks for your time.

My Mongo version is 3.4.6 and I am using PyMongo as my driver. You can see the query in action at [mongo-db-playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SOolELzKRDw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is might be bad idea to do all process in a aggregation query, you could do this in your client side,

I have created a query which is lengthy may cause performance issues in huge data,

- `$objectToArray` convert `months` object to array
- `$unwind` deconstruct months array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `transactions` array and provide index field `index`
- `$group` by `_id, year, month and index`, and get first object from transactions in fields
- `$project` you can design your response if you want otherwise this is optional i have added in playground link

```
my_db.collection.aggregate([
  { # some filter logic here to filter data basically first },
  { $project: { months: { $objectToArray: "$months" } } },
  { $unwind: "$months" },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$months.v.transactions",
      includeArrayIndex: "index"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        year: "$months.v.year",
        month: "$months.v.month",
        index: "$index"
      },
      fields: { $first: "$months.v.transactions" }
    }
  }
], allowDiskUse=True);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8f7jS8YyucC)

Comment: Interesting idea. Actually I was trying to flatten out ~4-5M records to CSV and the problem statement I shared is a hurdle for me actually. The trouble with your approach for me would me linking back with other details that I am fetching as well with these. I think I will have to join it back using lookup probably as after the project they won't be there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can add that other details in $group stage, just provide the details will try to solve if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try it in a day or so and see if I can crack the problem else I will definitely ping you here. Thanks again.

Comment: So I got it working by using unwind and addtofields operators and then I iterated over the same and it kinda automatically gave me data in separate rows.